# Can duplicate pg_hba entries result in a connection error?

Tags: postgresql-9.3, connectivity, pg-hba.conf

I have received the following error when attempting to connect to an Arch Linux server:

```
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionErrorreplication#monitor
PG::Error: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "45.56.86.24" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

but I have an entry in my pg_hba.conf file on that server:

```
hostssl replication replication 45.56.86.24/32 md5
```

Actually... there are two lines like this. Is presence of the second line be expected to result in this error?

Comment: pg_hba.conf in your case it's TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD hostssl replcation replication 45.56.86.24/32 md5 looks good... are You using Virtual machine?

Comment: Here you don't even get to the `pg_hba.conf`.  The problem is stated in the message: the host either does not listen on that port, or the port is not available from host trying to connect.  This latter can be a result of missing routing or firewalls or I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Duplicate entries are basically ignored.

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) of `pg_hba.conf` describes how the rules work pretty well:

> The first record with a matching connection type, client
>   address, requested database, and user name is used to perform
>   authentication. There is no "fall-through" or "backup": if one record
>   is chosen and the authentication fails, subsequent records are not
>   considered. If no record matches, access is denied.

So the second and any subsequent duplicates will never be considered.
So duplicate entires can not be the cause of your error.